# How to tour The White House with a group of people from different states

Tags: usa, washington-dc

I am trying to visit The White House with a group of people from different states which means we all have different representatives.

- Does each group member need to ask their representative?
- Or is it fine if we are all included in one request?
- If we need to ask our own representative, how do we coordinate a time?

Comment: Have you asked your Representative (or one of their public-facing staffmembers) how to accomplish this?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica that's the plan for tomorrow, but I'm hoping someone has experienced this issue already and has an answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to present your request to a member of Congress or their staff; tours can only be arranged through a member of Congress and the member's Congressional Tour Coordinator.

The [White House official government website](https://www.whitehouse.gov/visit/) says:

> Public tour requests are scheduled on a first come, first served basis and **must be submitted through a Member of Congress and their Congressional Tour Coordinator**. Constituents may reach your Member of Congress and Congressional Tour Coordinator through the U.S. House of Representatives Switchboard at 202-225-3121, the U.S. Senate Switchboard at 202-224-3121, or online at [www.congress.gov/members](http://www.congress.gov/members) (emphasis added)

Comment: The key point in the quoted passage seems to be "submitted through _a_ Member of Congress", not "their Member". Obviously, the best person to reach out to is somebody who serves you, but it doesn't seem to state that they can't arrange it for others. Therefore, OP should reach out to the person who represents their group leader, or perhaps the member who represents the most out of the group.

Comment: Can confirm, only need to reach out to one representative.